# Plot from for loop and legend from same loop dont match colors. How can I have them correspond. MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, match, legend

```
for j= 1:numfiles;
   plot(A(j,:))
   legendmatrix{j,1}=strcat('Run',num2str(j))
   hold all
end
legend(legendmatrix)
```

`hold all` allows me to have different colors for all my curves. However when I use the strings from `strcat` and display them on the plot, not enough colors are used and they are not assigned to the corresponding curve.

In this case plot 1 is run 1 in the legend, etc... and I want the colors to match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a slightly different example:

```
%# sample data
N = 7;
A = rand(N,10);
x = 1:10;

%# plot each with a specific color
hold on
clr = lines(N);    %# LINES colormap
for j=1:N
   plot(x, A(j,:), 'Color',clr(j,:))
end
hold off

%# add legend
str = cellstr( num2str((1:N)','Run%d') );
legend(str)
```

[image: screenshot]

Note that if N>7, the [LINES](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/colormap.html) colormap will start to repeat colors, but you can always specify your own set of colors... You also have the option of using different markers and line-styles to get more visually distinct data.

Answer (score 0):

Used Amros example below and made the data easier for visualization of concept and used jet colormap instead to support more than 7 different colors:

```
%# sample data
N = 15;

x = 1:10;

A = rand(N,10)./2;
A = A + repmat((1:N)',1,10);

%# plot each with a specific color
hold on
clr = jet(N);    %# LINES colormap
for j=1:N
   plot(x, A(j,:), 'Color',clr(j,:))
end
hold off

%# add legend
str = cellstr( num2str((1:N)','Run%d') );
legend(str)
```

As you can see from the results, the legend is correct, and you can plot a lot more lines:
[image]